# Problem Loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65) and Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 using a USB drive with Etcher. My laptop is the Lenovo Legion Y720. I proceeded to disable secure boot and when I clicked try Ubuntu. The error messages appeared, namely:

> 6.432927 Problem loading UEFI: db X.509 certificate (-65)
>   6.434510 Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000000e
>   6.762780 0000:01:00.0: read fault at 0000000000 engine if [PHYSICAL] client 07 BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell
>   (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands. (initramfs) Unable
>   to find a miedum containing a live file system.

I am stumped and do not know how to proceed to install Ubuntu. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop as you and I get that text popping up too, but it then proceeds normally to boot up, have you tried waiting?